# Testflight - Notify internal tester does not work

Tags: ios, xcode7, app-store-connect, testflight

Oh, I am tired of Apple, because it's hard even to understand what's going on there...

I submited new build yesterday and receive an email:

> The following build has completed processing:
>
> Platform: iOS App Name: AppName Build Number: 3 Version Number: 1.7
>   App SKU: 0000 App Apple ID: 00000000 You can now use this build for
>   TestFlight testing or submit it to the App Store.

So I've checked Testflight menu on iTunes Connect and selected Internal Testing tab, so looks like build is there and it's selected.

As I have not received any email with install button to install build, I've selected "Not Available for Testing" on the same internal testing menu and then reselect build one more time:

1. Stop testing:

[image]

2. Selecting a build one more time:

[image]

3. Notify testers:

[image]

One more why it's annoying that when you are even a developer with good experience it has no difference for you, because with Apple it's every time something new and all time it does not work as you expect...

So as you see it will notify 6 tester, one of them it's my email. Before I received email with install button, but now there is no email even after reselecting build (I did it 5 times). Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

1. Sometimes iTunes Connect lags and your invitation emails get queued up but not sent until a few hours later. It's frustrating I know, but I would give it some time before doing anything else.
2. There used to be an iTunes Connect beta testing bug where you would have to toggle the beta testing switch on and off in order for invitation emails to get sent for the updated version of your app. I'd think Apple would have fixed that by now, but you can always give that a shot.
3. If you're not receiving your invitation within 24 hours, the best thing you can do is contact Apple directly and get developer support: https://developer.apple.com/contact/

iTunes Connect can be incredibly temperamental at times so I understand your frustration. Sorry I couldn't be of more help. It's unfortunate, but there's not a lot developers can do when things go wrong on the iTunes Connect side. Best of luck!

Comment: you're welcome! I'm glad you finally got it working :)